# Why does an inconsistent linear system have no "real" solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Elementary algebra students are often taught that a system of linear equations like:

\begin{align}
y &= x\\
y &= x+1
\end{align}

has "no **real** solution". This seems to imply that there may be a complex solution, but this does not seem to be the case.

Is there a reason that the answer should not simply be "no solution"?

Comment: In a next section of a pre calculus book, students may have to solve a system that contain quadratic expressions and thus complex solutions could be solutions. If both sections are in the same chapter, then I can understand the conclusion "No real solutions" When it comes strictly to graphing and points of intersections, then of course you are right. There are no solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remind students that in that course, at least for now, only real numbers are being considered, they probably included the word "real" reflexively.

There are other number systems (like the integers modulo $2$) where things like $x=x+1+1$ can be true, though.

Comment: That's a good point. The domain is implicitly the reals, so there is no damage done by being specific with your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Real and complex numbers aren't the only "thing" out there. There are also matrices, vectors, extended reals, fields of different orders, etc.

A solution **must** be a solution with respect to some "thing".

This has a solution in the extended reals, trivial ring, etc.

Don't think of "real" as "not complex", think of "real" as a specific set of things.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Thanks for the reframe. :)

Comment: @b1008745 Good question btw, +1

Answer (score 0):

The system implies $x=y=x+1$. Hence $0=1$. Which is not possible in a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29), should that be $\mathbb{Q, R, C...}$

Comment: Not that you're wrong, but I don't know if this really explains the confusion.